# How to add xcode text macro

Tags: xcode

How to create custom code completion macros in Xcode. I googled but I don't find anything

for example, when i was '[' xcode add text '[""]'

it can possible ?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**
In Xcode 11 and later, the library is accessed via the + button in the project window's tool bar. Hold the option key as you click the button to make the Library window persistent so that you can drag your snippet into it. There's also an **Editor->Create Code Snippet** menu item that creates a new snippet from any selected text.

**Original answer:**
It's easy to add your own completions, but this might be one of Xcode's most under appreciated features. Select some text and then drag and drop the selected text in the snippets library in the lower right corner (icon looks like `{}`):

[image: snippet library]

You can then double-click the new snippet to edit the name, completion shortcut, scope, language, etc., as well as the text of the snippet itself. If you want to add tokens for the user to fill in similar to what the built-in snippets do for parameters, denote them as `<#yourtoken#>` in the snippet text. There's more information in the docs at [Creating a Custom Code Snippet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html).

[image: headerdoc snippet]

Comment: How to access it with a shortcut? Lets say I added === as shortcut. Now how can I get the code?

Comment: Once you've created a snippet with a given completion shortcut, you just type that shortcut into the text editor and the completion should pop up as a possibility. Just hit return to insert the snippet. The snippet won't appear if the platform, language, or scope don't match what you've set for the snippet, though -- that prevents your Objective-C snippets from appearing when you're writing Swift code, or your iOS snippets from appearing when you're writing MacOS X code.

Comment: I wrote a small snippet in swift and it doesn't appear after typing the shortcut. Even the default while and for loop snippets are not working as they dont autocomplete like they use to in Obj C. I am using Xcode 7.1.1 and swift 2.1

Comment: Works for me, but not with the shortcut `===`. I suspect that's because `===` is a valid operator in Swift. If you use `eee` as the shortcut instead, it pops right up.

Comment: Makes sense.. But what about default for and while loops. Why they are not autocompleted like they use to in ObjC

Comment: That's just a matter of Xcode not including snippets for those control structures. It only takes a moment to create your own.